# Swift - Creating a cloze text (text with gaps where users can type in a string)

Tags: swift

I am wondering how I can create a cloze with swift in xcode?

Of course, I could take a separate label or text field and let the user input something. But I would like to create a function that generates a cloze text like this (without a separate text field), where the user has to type a word in:

Hello, my name is _______.

Let me know if you require any further details.

Peter

Comment: if you want to do this all in an editable textfield, you'll need to make a custom text field that only allows editing on certain portions of text (anything before the attributed string that contains underlines should not be editable). Prevent the editing and the cursor will stay after the is  and use an attributed string to add the underline to the inserted text. You will have to expand the text when the user continues to enter beyond a base limit if your underline doesn't match that limit. In reality, this is something you should do with a separate textField/label/etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply TheCodingArt!
I tried to put it into practice and found out that I have to convert the string into an "NSMutableAttributedString" if I'm right?

However, I cannot find the Swift command for "make this string editable for the user" and "make this string non-editable for the user".

Does anyone know how to do this?